# AS3 Going to prevFrame from child

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ok so I have problem with changing frame.(I'll say it step-by-step)Basically I created from jpeg->MovieClip(record),and in this movieclip I created manually button.Then in MainClass by addchild(record) I added it to the stage.Now by modifications on class record I created functional button,and now by clicking it I wants to go to the prevFrame.

```
public class MainClass extends MovieClip
{
    var x:boolean=false;
    static var ramka3:MovieClip;
    public function MainClass()
    {
        stop();
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,rrr);
    }
    function rrr():void
    {
     if(x==false)
     {
       x=true;
        ram3 = new record ();
        ram3.x = stage.stageWidth / 20;
        ram3.y = stage.stageHeight / 4;
        ram3.width = stage.stageWidth / 1.1;
        ram3.height = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        addChild(record);
      }
    }
```

Record Class:

```
public class record extends MovieClip
{
    public function record()
    {
        Restart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,RestartGame);
        MainMenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,RestartGame);

    }
    function RestartGame(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var button:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.currentTarget);
        if (button==Restart)
        {
            gotoAndStop(2);//nothing do
        }
        if (button==MainMenu)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the code for what you've tried please.

Comment: So I quess no one know ,what is going on ?